# Azure Databricks: How to delete files of a particular extension outside of DBFS using python

Tags: pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks

I am able to delete a file of a particular extension from the directory **/databricks/driver** using the bash command in databricks.

```
%%bash

rm /databricks/driver/file*.xlsx
```

But I am unable to figure out, how to access and delete a file outside of dbfs in a python script,

I think using dbutils we cannot access files outside of DBFS and the below command outputs False as its looking in DBFS.

```
dbutils.fs.rm("/databricks/driver/file*.xlsx")
```

I am eager to be corrected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure how to do it using dbutils but I am able to delete it using glob

```
import os
from glob import glob

for file in glob('/databricks/driver/file*.xlsx'):
  os.remove(file)
```

Comment: Glad to know that your issue has resolved. You can accept it as an answer( click on the checkmark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Comment: sure  @CHEEKATLAPRADEEP-MSFT.Thank you :-)